# Randomizing array with no limit, then splitting it up equally in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var players = [];
var totalplayers = 0
var team1 = [];
var team2 = [];

var commands = {
"teams.join": {
    name: "Join random team.",
    description: "Anybody who joins will be put to a team",
    process: function(bot, msg, suffix) {   
        players.push(msg.sender);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, players);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, msg.sender + " has been added to the random team selection.");
        totalplayers += 1;
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, totalplayers)
    },
},
"teams.random": {
    name: "Random team selection.",
    desciption: "Displays all players in random team selection in a random team.",
    process: function(bot, msg, suffix) {
        var playcount = 0;
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "tp: " + totalplayers); // Check
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "i: " + playcount); // Check
        for (playcount = 0; playcount < totalplayers; playcount++) { 
            //bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "Looping?") // Check
            var Rteam = players[Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length)];
            //bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, Rteam); // Check

            if (playcount = 0 || 2 || 4 || 6 || 8) {
                team1.push(Rteam);
                bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "isEven = true"); // Check
                playcount + 1;
            } else if (playcount = 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 9) {
                team2.push(Rteam);
                bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "isEven = false"); // Check
                playcount + 1;
            } 
        playcount + 1;  
        var roll = players.splice(Rteam, 1);
        var yourNumber = roll[totalplayers];
        //i += 1;
        } 
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "Team 1: " + team1);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.channel, "Team 2: " + team2);
    },  
}
```

`teams.join` works fine, but I included to show the whole section of the `teams`. `teams.random` should take the `players` array, randomise the players (users) locations in the array, then distribute them so that `players[0]` is on Team 1, `players[1]` is on Team 2 (etc.) until there are no more users left. Essentially it is taking a list and splitting it up into two groups randomly. The main thing I realized while testing this is that `playcount` doesn't increment (I've tried For, While and Do-Until loops to no avail.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the code related only to your question. If you want to know how to split an array, post your code showing that you trying to do this. And we could help more easy.

Comment: `playcount + 1` doesn't do anything. It calculates the sum, but doesn't put it anywhere.

Comment: What's the purpose of `var roll = players.splice(Rteam, 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
if (playcount = 0 || 2 || 4 || 6 || 8) {
```

There are two problems: First, you're using `=`, which is assignment, when it should be `==` for comparison. Second, you can't use `||` that way to compare against multiple elements, you need to do the comparisons separately for each item. So it should be:

```
if (playcount == 0 || playcount == 2 || playcount == 4 || playcount == 6 || playcount == 8) {
```

But if you want to know if `playcount` is even, you can just do:

```
if (playcount % 2 == 0)
```

You don't need to use `else if` for the other test, just use `else`, since there are just two possibilities.

The lines that contain:

```
playcount + 1;
```

don't do anything. You don't need this at all, since you're incrementing `playcount` in the `for()` header.

By the way, there's nothing in your code that prevents you from selecting the same player multiple times, and adding them to different teams.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barmar on his comments about the OP original code.
But for completeness sake, here's a sample code to split the teams in half and randomly place players in each team.

```
var players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    team1 = [],
    team2 = [],
    i;

while (players.length > 0) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length);
    if (players.length % 2 === 0) {
        team1.push(players[i]);
    } else {
        team2.push(players[i]);
    }
    players.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(team1, team2);
```

Output:

```
[10, 4, 1, 6, 5] [3, 8, 2, 9, 7]
```

Run the code in browser console a few times, you'll get different random numbers in each array.